# last_rev is higher? with git svn rebase

Tags: git, git-svn

I use

```
git svn fetch
git svn rebase
git filter-branch -f --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all
git push origin master
```

to maintain a git mirror of an svn repo.

The mirror is one way so nothing should flow back from git into svn.

Recently I started seeing the following:

```
Partial-rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.7211e2ad-34f8-b74a-be6e-23ccad239578 ...
Currently at 83725 = f638db2f388f295dc4d7da0df9ffe8cfb74a1dd1
last_rev is higher!: 83725 >= 83699 at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 570.

Rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.7211e2ad-34f8-b74a-be6e-23ccad239578 ...
r30469 = 30ef2b7272b91dd6d436e46f1c8447818a52dbfb
r30479 = fc195960e09726deef537e942bc1880cffb44525
r30592 = 1071bbb7f352d21f1ed76c48645617b5913c6abc
...
...
r83699 = 841e6c8de9d649be040b3ea9e97ea145c40e083f
r83722 = 0c93f70e36fe9928f49a207d9a73cef5dcb0e192
r83725 = 7b9bab1644d3fa69999169fd0b7909b4d3c5d6e4
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.7211e2ad-34f8-b74a-be6e-23ccad239578
    A           somepath/somefile.xml
r83739 = 2e7078cbad311f57e8648031d3454525076f049a (refs/remotes/git-svn)
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to refs/remotes/git-svn.
Rewrite 5b462f2a2cc89120068fd6d17fdfe5775461fa1e (2785/2971) (2788 seconds passed, remaining 186 predicted)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/git-svn' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 1.51 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.company.com:uname/repo.git
   7b9bab1..2e7078c  master -> master
Current branch master is up to date.
```

What does this mean?

Did someone monkey with the svn changelog somewhere?

Should I start the mirror over from scratch?

or

Is there a way to make the current mirror state happy again?

Is my script for maintaining the mirror flawed in some way?

Comment: Have you looked to see what revisions 83699..83275 are, and whether they're being filtered out?

Comment: While setting up git mirror did you use `git svn clone` command ?
Did you commit something to git mirror after it was setup ?

Comment: [This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion#Pulling-in-New-Changes) might help you.